# How to setup ElmahCore for a Console Application?

Tags: .net-core, console-application, elmah

I want to log errors for a console application using Elmah.I've found ElmahCore and elmah.io.core but I don't know how to setup any of them on a console app.I'm using .net core.

Comment: Are you developing a .NET Core or .NET full framework console application? You have tagged your question with "asp.net-core", but if I understand you correctly, your application isn't a web app, right?

Comment: a .Net Core console application.I'm sorry I'll change the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELMAH (the open source project) doesn't work with .NET Core. ElmahCore has a lot of dependencies to ASP.NET Core, but if you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var log = new MemoryErrorLog();
        log.Log(new Error(new Exception()));
        var errors = new List<ErrorLogEntry>();
        var result = log.GetErrors(0, 10, errors);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(errors);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You can replace `MemoryErrorLog` with a target logger of your choice.

The package named `elmah.io.core` is a deprecated package from [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/). elmah.io is (among other things) a commercial cloud version of ELMAH, where you store all of your errors in the cloud ([list of differences between ELMAH and elmah.io](https://docs.elmah.io/elmah-and-elmah-io-differences/)). elmah.io works with .NET core through either the [Elmah.Io.Client](https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-console-application/) NuGet package or using one of the integrations for popular logging frameworks like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/).

I wouldn't recommend you to use ElmahCore for logging in a console application. It is created for ASP.NET Core. There are much better options for logging from a console application, like the mentioned logging frameworks.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Did it answer your question? If yes, feel free to mark my response as the answer :D

Comment: Yes, thank you !
Your response was informative and very useful ,I marked it as the answer.